# What is the name of the planet that Luke Skywalker is on at the end of Star Wars 7?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

*Star Wars 7* introduced Luke Skywalker in the end of the movie, but where is this planet that he is at? Can someone tell me the name?

Comment: In the movie, "Ach-to".  In real life, "Skellig Michael".

Comment: I believe it was on a planet known as "Earth"

Comment: The dupe question addresses both the question of the planetary name ***and*** the system.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Ahch-to

The planet Luke is on at the end of the film is called [Ahch-to](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahch-To).

> Ahch-To was an aquatic planet which served, three decades after the Galactic Civil War, as the home to Jedi Master Luke Skywalker, who went into exile seeking the first Jedi Temple after his new generation of Jedi were killed by Kylo Ren. Ahch-To had numerous islands, which Skywalker sought out during his exile. After the Resistance pieced together two map fragments to reveal Skywalker's location, Rey traveled to Ahch-To in the Millennium Falcon accompanied by R2-D2 and Chewbacca, in search of him.

That's about all we know about it at this point.

[image]

---

**Out-of-universe**: The location was filmed on Skellig Michael.

> Skellig Michael [...] is the larger of the two Skellig Islands, 11.6 kilometres (7.2 mi) west of the Iveragh Peninsula in County Kerry, Ireland. A Christian monastery was founded on the island at some point between the 6th and 8th century and remained continuously occupied until it was abandoned in the late 12th century. The remains of the monastery, and most of the island, became a UNESCO World Heritage Site in 1996.
> <sub>- [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellig_Michael)</sub>

Comment: Might want to add the real name - Skellig Michael.  Off the southwest tip of Ireland.  Now a seabird sanctuary, once a monastery.

Comment: bless you! : ) : )

Comment: @WadCheber done, thanks. :)

Comment: @RedCaio me chama no Twitter at vmesel para a gente bater um papo, estou montando uma matéria!

Comment: That's Skellig Michael? Oh wow, I had no idea—never actually saw any footage from there. So I guess Rey might literally be climbing the “fourteen steps to nowhere, out of solid stone / won't lead us to the Heavens or lead us to the sea” (that a—probably extremely obscure—lyrics reference).

Comment: Gezundheit. :-)

Comment: @ViniciusMesel Minha resposta resolveu sua pergunta? Ou há algo mais que eu deveria incluir?

Comment: Não, está tudo certinho @RedCaio

Answer (score 4):

### The planet is called "Ahch-To".

From the leaked WGA script:

> EXT. AHCH-TO - DAY
>
> A pristine and mighty OCEAN.  Endless BLUE, dotted with random, beautiful, mountainous BLACK ROCK ISLANDS, dotted with countless GREEN TREES.
>
> The Millennium Falcon FLIES INTO VIEW, BANKS towards one of the ISLANDS.

...

> EXT. AHCH-TO ISLAND - STONE STRUCTURES - DAY
>
> Rey arrives at a clearing. Small, modest, primitive stone structures. But no one around. Rey walks past them, sees, senses no one.
>
> And then she stops. Feels something. She turns. Standing forty feet away from her, his back to us, is a MAN, in a CLOAK AND ROBE.
>
> Rey stares, knowing exactly who it is. But she just stares for what seems like forever. Until he finally TURNS, SLOWLY, to her. Pulls back his hood.
>
> IT IS LUKE SKYWALKER.

Lucasfilm's Pablo Hidalgo confirmed this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/682745067392471040):

> So if you can see the WGA script, yes, the name of the planet from the end of the movie is there.

[image]

As does *Star Wars:  The Force Awakens:  The Visual Dictionary*, and - as seen in this picture - *Star Wars:  Rey's Story*:

[image]

> Those words were still echoing in Rey's head as she flew the *Falcon* high above Ahch-To...  Rey recognized the landscape from her dreams.